# Gram–Schmidt algorithm used for obtaining the orthogonal and orthonormal

Tags: inner-products, orthogonality, orthonormal

Why are both the algorithm used for finding the orthogonal and orthonormal basis the same? I'm relying on a set of slides given by by lecturer (known to be sloppy!) and I want to confirm if it should be the same.

Edit:

[image]

As can be seen, the algorithm are both the same!

Answer (score 2):

They are not entirely the same. The process for obtaining the orthogonal basis results in an orthogonal basis that is not necesseraly orthonormal.

In fact, one process is a subprocess in the other. If $B$ is a basis, then the Gram-Schmidt algorithm converts $B$ into $B'$ which is also a basis of the same space as $B$, but it is an orthogonal basis. Then, if you want an orthonormal base, you have to normalize each vector in $B'$ to obtain $B''$.

---

Edit:

Judging by your notes, it seems to me that your professor names both processes "the Gram-Schmidt process", but the algorithms are most certainly **not** the same, as the other algorithm ends with:

$$v_n' = \frac{v_n}{\sqrt{\langle v_n, v_n\rangle}}$$

Comment: Edit made in OP

Comment: @Mathematicing Edit made in my answer.

Comment: I was under the impression they are both the not the same when I noted contradictions and issues while working through the tutorial sheets. Indeed, sloppy.

Answer (score 0):

An orthonormal basis is an orthogonal basis whose vectors have been scaled to have length $1$ under the norm induced by the inner product. That is, if you wish to find an orthogonal basis, it is enough to find an orthonormal one. Conversely, if you have an orthogonal basis, you may make it orthonormal by simply scaling each vector.

Comment: Is the converse true then? If it isn't true, then the same algorithm used for both process is suspect.
I can provide the algorithm from my notes if need be.

Comment: Edited to clarify that there is a sense in which the converse is true.

Comment: Also, why is there a distinction in the algorithm between normalised and un-normalised vectors? It does make everything exceedingly complicated. If the vectors are normalised, surely, the process of normalising it is trivial.

Comment: There are two ways you can carry out the algorithm: you can normalise as you go, or you can normalise everything at the end. The calculations are fiddlier if you normalise as you go, because you keep having to deal with horrible constants, but it ensures that the vectors stay reasonably-sized.

Comment: But if you normalise at the end, then you can skip the last step if you don't care about having ortho*normal* vectors, and that saves a bit of work.

Comment: Edit made in OP